# How to set the value of numpy.arange from the given data in SciPy?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have to set the range of `x` (here from 50 to 500) manually in the code:

```
data = plb.loadtxt('data.txt')  
x = data[:,0]
y= data[:,1]
cs = UnivariateSpline(x, y)
xs = np.arange(50, 500, .1)
plt.plot(x, y, label='A')
plt.plot(xs, cs(xs), label="B")
plt.xlim(50, 500)
```

How can I write the `np.arange` and `plt.xlim` to take the lowest and highest values of `x` given by the set of data (read from the file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use [`np.min`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html) and [`np.max`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html#numpy.amax):

```
import numpy as np

x_min = x.min()   # or np.min(x)
x_max = x.max()   # or np.max(x)

xs = np.arange(x_min, x_max+0.1, .1)

plt.xlim(x_min, x_max)
```

The `+0.1` is needed because the stop value is excluded in `np.arange`.

Note: Generally it's not needed to set `xlim` manually if you want the full extend of the values. I believe the default `xlim` already uses the `min` and `max` of the x values (maybe a bit modified).

Comment: Both tips were super handy! So silly of me to miss that the `xlim` arguments are optional.